# Can't access s3 buckets after creating instance using IAM profile

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, amazon-iam

I am trying to access some s3 buckets from an instance created applying the IAM profile that allows full access to those s3 buckets. I am able to carry out the required operations using `aws cli`. However, my application is written in Ruby and makes use of `fog` gem. Using fog, I am unable to access those buckets. All I get is Access Denied. Additionally, I grabbed the required keys:

`` aws_access_key_id=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/${instance_profile} | grep AccessKeyId | cut -d':' -f2 | sed 's/[^0-9A-Z]*//g'` ``


`` aws_secret_access_key=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/${instance_profile} | grep SecretAccessKey | cut -d':' -f2 | sed 's/[^0-9A-Za-z/+=]*//g'` ``

and tried to access the buckets. Again, access denied.

Is there anything I should have missed?

Comment: Instead of using fog gem, try [fog-aws](https://github.com/fog/fog-aws) gem. Hopefully it will solve your problem

Comment: Are the access permissions set on the S3 bucket or the IAM user?  Do the IAM user and S3 bucket belong to the same root AWS account?

Comment: @FrederickCheung, because I was able to list the buckets using aws cli which I presume uses boto. Correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta, I have set permissions to the IAM user and yes, the user belongs to the same root AWS account.

Comment: AWS CLI is built on botocore, not boto.  But boto does have full support for IAM Roles for credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as an access key and a secret access key, temporary credentials such as the ones provided by instance metadata also have a session token - without the token the credentials are invalid.

Current versions of fog / fog-aws support fetching instance credentials for you, eg

```
storage = Fog::Storage::AWS.new(region: "eu-west-1", use_iam_profile:true)
```

This will also refetch credentials before they expire

Comment: thanks @frederick, it worked. I need not even mention the region.